# G++ enable -fexceptions

Tags: c++11

i have created a C++ project for my STM32 using eclipse (SW4STM32, which is basicly eclipse CDT).
However I'm not able to set the exception flag.

```
error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
```

I searched the g++ compiler options but i could not find an option here. So I tried to add this flag as miscellaneous but no lock there :(
Could you give me a hint please?

[image: Compiler Eclipse Settings]

Comment: May be you named your C++ file as `.c` and it uses `gcc` to build it, instead of `g++`?

Comment: nope that is not it,
the console output shows the following 
`Building file: ../Src/User/SD/XML/pugixml.cpp
Invoking: MCU G++ Compiler` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try turning off "Disable handling exceptions (-fno-exceptions)".

`-fno-exceptions` is the opposite of `-fexceptions`, which is probably why the `-fexceptions` doesn't seem to be working.